# Detect if message is a reply

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Is there any way to detect if message sent by a user is a reply or a standard message, and respond to each of those accordingly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check to see if the [`Message#type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=type) property is equal to ["REPLY"](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageType)

---

To answer your other question about whether a bot can "reply to other messages", I don't believe discord.js V12 currently covers this part of the Discord API. I have seen this will be part of discord.js V13 though. The official message on the discord.js discord server is this:

> ✨ Discord.js will support inline replies in v13, replacing Message#reply with the new functionality.
> If you'd like to try out the feature ahead of time, please install the master branch of Discord.js
> You can e.g. use NPM to do this: `npm i discordjs/discord.js` (this requires `git` to be added to `PATH`)
> ⚠ : There are many more breaking changes on master than just replies! ⚠

Update: v13 is out, so yes bots using discord.js v13 can now reply to messages using `Message#reply`